# Put geospatial information on only part of a raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geospatial-pdf

I've seen PDFs where only part of the page is georeferenced; the end consumer of that kind of PDFs (being ForeFlight) shows a blue rectangle around the part that is georeferenced to show that. From the output of gdalinfo, I haven't understood where that is specified. Maybe in "neatline"? I haven't found an explanation in the documentation of the concept of "neatline", only how to set it.

How can I achieve that same result with GDAL?

I create PDFs from raster images (PNG format).

I currently do (in Python):

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
gdal.UseExceptions()
png_ds = gdal.Open(input_file_name, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
## computation for correct values for corners of whole PNG
png_ds.SetGeoTransform([ul_x, px_width, 0, ul_y, 0, px_height])
png_ds.SetProjection("WGS84")
pdfdriver=gdal.GetDriverByName('PDF')
pdf_ds=pdfdriver.CreateCopy('output_file_name', png_ds, 1)
```

but that tags as georeferenced the whole page area, not the subarea that is actually georeferenced. I try to correct by "backcomputing" what the upper left corner would have as latlong if one would "expand" the georeferenced area to it, but if I could do the tagging right in the first place?

For simplicity assume that the area to be georeferenced is a rectangle, and I have the coordinates in pixels of the corners of that area in the source PNG.

Comment: Is it only that part of the raster that is georeferenced, or does the blue line just show you the Area of Interest?

Comment: did "only part of the page is georeferenced" mean that only the part of the pdf page that contain a map is georeferenced (I mean a pdf page with a map and some text or other picture) or that only a part of a map is georeferenced ?

Comment: Only part of the raster is georeferenced, in the meaning that only part of the page contains a map that is georeferenced, the rest of the page is margins, text and other pictures.